# OctoberCMS Builder plugin, uploading file and storing in database

Tags: octobercms

I am new to **OctoberCMS** and i am trying to create one plugin using **builder plugin** itself which **OctoberCMS** provides [OctoberCMS Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder)  called something like "**Social Links**", everything working fine expect i am unable to understand the logic of uploading file to any directory and storing that name to my database table's particular field. My table's field name is "**social_logo**" in which i am trying to store the file name which will be uploaded.

I am able to upload file to default directory at the moment whichever **OctoberCMS** generating with the file i am uploading. But the thing is i am unable to store that particular file name to my database table's field.

Can someone guide me what should i do to achieve this ?

Here is the my model file what i have done so far.

**SocialLinks.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\SocialLinks\Models;

use Model;

/**
 * Model
 */
class Sociallink extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];

    /*
     * Disable timestamps by default.
     * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'technobrave_sociallinks_';


    public $attachOne = [
            'social_logo' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];

}
```

**Fields.yaml**

```
fields:
    social_logo:
        label: 'technobrave.sociallinks::lang.Sociallink.social_logo'
        span: auto
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        mode: file
        useCaption: true
        thumbOptions:
            mode: crop
            extension: auto
        type: fileupload
```

**columns.yaml**

```
columns:
    social_logo:
        label: 'technobrave.sociallinks::lang.Sociallink.social_logo'
        type: text
        searchable: true
        sortable: true
```

As you can see on above code, for now i have only 1 field because i am having issues with this particular field only while uploading an image, i want to store that file name . All other form attributes working for me like text,textarea etc so for now i m only trying to achieve this thing with this single field.

Can someone guide me what should i do to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, eventually i have solved this by following these steps.

First of all, we do not need to create any column in database table to store any **file upload names** in any field in database table as **OctoberCMS** will automatically in **system_files** table. So i simply removed '**social_logo**' field via **builder** plugin.

Then i removed old **file upload** control from my current **Social Links plugin** using **Builder plugin** from **admin** and simply created new one without setting up any relation with any table's field.

Then simply i went to **Sociallinks.php** model,and made sure this code is there

```
public $attachOne = [
            'social_logo' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
```

Also make sure your **mode** should be **image** and your **type** *can be* **fileupload** as i am able to see images in edit record section like this .. you can update this code though based on your needs but this works for me well so i put this code...

**fields.yaml**

```
fields:
    social_logo:
        label: 'Social Logo'
        mode: image
        span: auto
        type: fileupload
```

and then i went to admin area and created test template and in **Code** tab i put this code just to check single record for now,

```
use technobrave\sociallinks\Models\Sociallink;


function onStart()
{
    $this['model_data'] = Sociallink::first();
}
```

and in template markup, i simply put this

```
<img src="{{ model_data.social_logo.getPath() }}" />
```

and whoa, i can see image .. :)

> > Additionaly, if you want multiple data then you can put this code in **Code Tab**,

```
use technobrave\sociallinks\Models\Sociallink;


function onStart()
{
    $this['model_data'] = Sociallink::all();
}
```

And your html markup tab will contain following code,

```
<h2>Image List</h2>
<ul>
    {% for current_model_data in model_data %}
    <h3>{{ current_model_data.id }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ current_model_data.social_logo.getPath() }}" />


    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thanks for support guys .. hope this helps to someone who can be new to OctoberCMS.. highly appreciated ..

Thank you ..

Comment: It's very nice. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: To put this shorter: You need the `$attachOne` in the model, can use the default file upload in the fields.yaml and display it as `record.image.getPath()` in the frontend. `image` being the file upload field name.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to display the images in the list via `columns.yaml`?

Answer (score 2):

If it is necessary for you to have the file name stored in the database, the best way might be to use the [Media Finder Widget](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-mediafinder) instead of the [File Upload Widget](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-fileupload), and remove the attachOne relationship from your model.

- The MediaFinder widget lets you store files anywhere within the `storage/media` subdirectory of your OctoberCMS installation, choosing the exact storage path therein that you want, and simply returns the stored file path as a string - that you then need to store as a column in the database record for your model, just as you seem to have had in mind.
- The File upload widget, combined with the attachOne (or attachMany) relationship works much differently. The attachOne (or attachMany) relationship does not correspond to an actual database column for your model. The information which files are attached to what other models here or there is stored and retrieved elsewhere - how exactly, I don't know. (The information about uploaded files through the File upload widget and their storage paths (which are generated randomly with no user control) are stored in the `system_files` database table - how the association is made to the parent models where the files are attached, I have no clue.)

You already have a file name column in your database table, and it seems that you would like your file names to be somehow "nice" and readable and perhaps under user control.
So I would suggest that you simply change your **fields.yaml** like so:

```
fields:
    social_logo:
        label: 'technobrave.sociallinks::lang.Sociallink.social_logo'
        span: auto
        oc.commentPosition: ''
        type: mediafinder
        thumbOptions:
            mode: crop
            extension: auto
```

(I don't know if the `thumbOptions` settings work here. You can try and see. As for the `useCaption` it can not be used here, since files in the media library are simply referenced by strings and have no corresponding eloquent model with additional information like `title` and `description`, as the File Upload files do.)

Comment: If you sticked to the original ```attachOne``` and ```fileupload``` solution, you have a file object attached to your model, which has a ```path``` attribute that returns the global url path to that file. You could access it simply like this in the template: (assuming you have some variable of that model type called sociallink): ```<img src="{{sociallink.social_logo.path}}">```

Comment: If you have implemented with the media finder solution that I suggested, then your ```social_logo``` field is simply a string containing the file path *relative to the OctoberCMS app/media/ directory*. There is a twig filter 'media' which makes a full url from it, like this. ```<img src="{{sociallink.social_logo | media}}">```

Comment: Now I see what you did there. You are using the builderList component from October's builder plugin. (I did not know that one before.)
So you simply added this declaration ```{% set sociallink = builderList.sociallink %}``` which makes no sense, because sociallink is not an attribute of the builderList component, but of the records that you are trying to display. (The records are of your ```Sociallink``` model, I hope). Try ```<img src="{{record.social_logo.path}}">```.

Comment: i have added my answer .. please have a look :) Thanks for you efforts .. highly appreciated ..