# how to display images from an multiple input file in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I would like to display the images that I uploaded in a multiple input file;
the input file is located in a form that targets my display page:

---

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ 'etape_4'|page }}" accept-charset="UTF8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onTest">
                {{form_token()}}
                {{form_sessionkey()}}



 Upload photo: <input  name="photo[]" type="file" id="photo" multiple="multiple"  />



<div class=" col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Suivant</button>


</div>


</form>
```

---

and here is the display page:

---

```
title = "etape_4"
url = "/etape_4"
is_hidden = 0
==
<?php



function onStart()
{

    $this['file'] = new \System\Models\File;
     $this['file']->fromFile(Input::file('photo'));

}

?>
==
<ul>
{%for image in file%}

<li>

{{image.path}}

<img src="{{image.path}}">
{%endfor%}

</li>
</ul>
```

---

when i choose the images and submit the page i get this error:

> is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given

so what is the solution ?
please help me !

Comment: Check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174178/octobercms-builder-plugin-uploading-file-and-storing-in-database/40235943#40235943

Comment: i checked it but that's not what i want,thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are `uploading multiple files and treating them as single file Object`

> lets correct `onStart` method to support multiple files

```
function onStart()
{
    $files = [];
    $multipleFiles = Input::file('photo');
    foreach($multipleFiles as $singleFile) {
        $fileModel = new \System\Models\File;
        $fileModel->fromFile($singleFile);
        $files[] = $fileModel;
    }
    $this['file'] = $files;
}
```

> Just replace your `onStart` code with this one it should work.

If any doubts please comment.

Comment: yes hardik satasiya,this is exactly the answer;thank you so much:)